# Why do clouds appear pinkish after rain?

Tags: visible-light, everyday-life, atmospheric-science, weather

Monsoon winds are blowing over India and after every rain I observe that the clouds are turning pinkish, even during the night.

What causes such a phenomena? Or are the observations coincidence?

Comment: Don't sand storms typically precede the monsoons?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you observe this effect at morning/evening times? The clouds are reflecting the sunlight which, due to its angle at these hours, appears 'reddish' due to it not being as heavily scattered. The pink colour is from this reflection off the grey rain cloud. :)

EDIT: In fact googling 'atmospheric optics' produces some websites that might be useful!